# iPhone option menus

Tags: iphone, menu, contextmenu, optionmenu

What options do I have when creating menu with options (contextual menus). What is allowed and what does Apple provide?

I have a toolbar with buttons and a click of a button opens a menu with options:

Examples:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPopoverControllers are only available on iPads, but it's ok to create similar looking things for iPhone

What you see in the picture, is entirely custom. a UIView subclass likely. There are pretty much no limits to what you do with your UI, within reason, so no ugly highly contrasting primary/secondary colours, and it's best to keep it at least similar to the native UI. If you say use a windows 7 phone ui style in an iPhone app it's more likely to get rejected by Apple, than keeping to the style of iOS.

So make it look as "professional" as possible, using gradients and shadows, edge arrows, like in the above picture.

Apple provides pretty much nothing that your looking for,

Answer (score 0):

Similar built-in widgets would be UIPopoverController (iPad-only) or UIActionSheet. I like your menu better though.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend looking at the guidelines for such *custom* UI elements.  I can not say what is 'allowed', but Apple is not shy about how your app should look/feel/function.

Towards the top of this link talks about toolbars, status bars, etc.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1